# Send text from client to server using json and ws

Tags: node.js

I am writing a nodejs server and client. The client will input text and send to the server using JSON and ws. Then, the server will display the text received.

Expect: client input 123, server display 123 Received.

now: client input 123, server display undefinedReceived.

this is server.js

```
var WebSocket = require('ws');
var WebSocketServer = WebSocket.Server;
var server = new WebSocketServer({port:8075});

console.log('server started');

server.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('message', function(message) {
    var json=JSON.parse(message);
if(json.body === 'connect') {
  socket.send('connected');
  console.log('connected');
}
else{
console.log(json.body + 'Received');
}
  });

  socket.on('close', function(msg, disconnect) {
    console.log(msg + ' ' + disconnect);
  });
});
```

this is client.js

```
var WebSocket = require('ws');
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8075");

ws.onopen = ('connect', function(connect) {
  let obj={};
  obj.name='data'
  message = 'connect';
  obj.body=message;
  ws.send(JSON.stringify(message));
});

process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

process.stdin.on('data', function(message) {
  let obj={};
  obj.name='data'
  message = message.trim();
  obj.body=message;
  ws.send(JSON.stringify(message), console.log.bind(null, 'Sent : ', message));
});

ws.on('message', function(message) {
  console.log(message);
});

ws.on('close', function(code) {
  console.log('Disconnected: ' + code);
});

ws.on('error', function(error) {
  console.log('Error: ' + error.code);
});
```

where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues here:

1) You're sending the wrong thing in Client.js - you want to send the 'obj' variable, not the 'message' variable. 
2) In Server.js you're trying to access 'message.data' which doesn't exist
3) You need to parse the JSON response first

So you want to have it like so:

```
socket.on('message', function(message) {
    var json=JSON.parse(message);
    if (json.body === 'connect') {
        ...
```

And in Client.js:

```
ws.send(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I find the problem in the server but I cannot find the problem in the client. It is a careless mistake and my skill is not good. thank you.

Comment: No worries! This sort of thing is a progress, you will get there. Good luck!